# How to Run FasterSeg on Jetson Nano

Tags: python-3.6, python-3.7, ubuntu-18.04, semantic-segmentation, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have encountered an issue, and I hope to run the FasterSeg model on Jetson Nano. I followed the steps on the original author's GitHub website and tried to align my system environment as closely as possible with the recommended setup by the author. However, I got some problems.

[FasterSeg](https://github.com/VITA-Group/FasterSeg)

Previously attempted to install it on a virtual machine with Ubuntu 16.04, and I successfully installed the required files from the requirements.txt. However, during testing, I encountered errors due to the virtual machine lacking a GPU. As a result, I decided to switch to using a physical Jetson Nano for testing

Due to Ubuntu having two versions of Python built-in, I attempted to create a virtual environment using Virtualenv on Ubuntu. Initially, I successfully set up the virtual environment. However, issues arose when I tried to execute the following instruction.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

An unexpected issue occurred during the installation of Matplotlib.

```
Building wheel for matplotlib (setup.py) ... еггог

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.

exit code: 1

[524 Lines of output]
```

I'm currently stuck at this point and unable to proceed further with implementing FasterSeg on Jetson Nano